# Does each request in ASP.NET MVC, share static variables with other requests?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Can I store my active Entity framework Database Context for the request, as a static property somewhere, so it's easily fetchable from Validators, helpers etc.

**E.G set it from a global action filter onto a static class as

```
public static DBContext GlobalHelper.ActiveDbContextForRequest;
```

Does each request share these static properties though? If they do I suppose it cannot work.

Comment: Static variables will/can only be shared [to all threads] across the *same* application domain. Multiple work processes naturally have different application domains. I would avoid the pattern of using static variables and instead use DI which solves this problem cleanly - being able to specify services (including "convenience properties") and control lifetimes (single/request/shared) easily.

Comment: Thank you!, (gosh there's always more to learn isn't there!!). So this is why people use DI? Do you recommend any DI library?

Comment: I use DI because I'm lazy >:D (I used to use static variables, but I "saw the light" with constructor-injection when it can be applied throughout the entire stack. Also, ReSharper really helps with automatically adding new members based off of constructor arguments.) My current favorite DI is Autofac (for WS + ASP.NET WebForms), but there are many many choices. Just make sure it has the appropriate integration (which should be for everything mainstream) to make the setup easy/trivial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, static variables are shared across the entire application (over all threads). You cannot safely access these variables without synchronization from various requests (since each request is handled on a different thread).

Even if you synchronize access to these variables, there's only a single instance of the static variable so all threads will see the same value - you can't have request-specific values this way.

Comment: Note: Request specific *static* variables can be established with the use of [Thread-local Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6sby1byh(v=vs.100).aspx) and correct setup/teardown (I believe there is a guarantee about a thread exclusive per "normal" request). However, DI is a *much* cleaner solution - I mention this only to point out that static variables *can* be made thread-local and do not imply that they should be used.

Comment: @user2246674 Yes, you're correct although TLS variables are not truly static - they are allocated per thread.

Answer (score 1):

Static variables are global for the whole application domain by default so the answer is yes, they are shared by all requests served by it.

Comment: *cough* whole application domain *cough*. I work on systems > 1 process (and > 1 server). In the past I've created some problems for myself assuming a single (or permanent) application domain handling all requests - definitely needs to be treated with caution or dev > test/production can go awry.

Comment: @user2246674: you're correct, changed process by application domain.